# Firefox not updating application associations in Preferences on a Windows machine

Tags: java, windows, firefox, permissions

When a JNLP is launched from a Firefox browser, the first time, it shows the following [image: dialog]. If I check the "do this automatically" check box, from the next time on, it doesn't ask this question.

The preferences seem to get stored in Firefox-> Options-> General-> Preferences.

[image: Preferences]

This works just fine on my machine. At a customer site, it doesn't seem to get updated. Even after checking the checkbox, each time it asks again & preferences also don't seem to get updated. What kind of permission/privilege issues could be causing this? How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 3):

Try and reinstall Firefox on the customer site